# How to define type so I am able to assign a Record with generic string key to custom enum key

Tags: typescript

My app receives data of know flags (basically key-value object) but I am only interested in subset of those flags. I want to write a types which are not just records like `Record<string, FlagDataModel>` but I want every flag to be identified byt `enum`. I started like this:

```
interface FlagsDataModel<
    T extends Record<string, FlagDataModel> = Record<string, FlagDataModel>
> {
    flags?: T;
}

interface FlagDataModel<T = boolean> {
    value: T;
}
```

As I want these flags to be identified by `enum` I added:

```
enum CustomNames {
    FOO = 'custom-foo',
    BAR = 'custom-bar'
}

type CustomFlagsDataModel = FlagsDataModel<{
    [CustomNames.BAR]: FlagDataModel,
    [CustomNames.FOO]: FlagDataModel
}>;
```

API may return data like this but I am only interested in subset of those:

```
// mock
const genericFlagsData: FlagsDataModel = {
    flags: {
        'custom-foo': { value: true },
        'custom-bar': { value: true },
        'custom-foobar': { value: true },
        'custom-barfoo': { value: true }
    }
};
```

At the end I would like to assign those API `genericFlagsData` to my `customFlagsData` and access the data by using an `enum` values as a key:

```
const customFlagsData: CustomFlagsDataModel = genericFlagsData; // Error occurs 
console.log(customFlagsData[CustomNames.BAR]) // <-- should log { value: true }
```

Error message:

```
Type 'FlagsDataModel<Record<string, FlagDataModel<boolean>>>' is not assignable to type 'CustomFlagsDataModel'. Type 'Record<string, FlagDataModel<boolean>>' is missing the following properties from type '{ "custom-bar": FlagDataModel<boolean>; "custom-foo": FlagDataModel<boolean>; }': [CustomNames.BAR], [CustomNames.FOO]
```

I have added the example on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2&ssl=36&ssc=41&pln=34&pc=39#code/PTAEEEAUElQcwKYDsECcCWBjAzgWAFDpIAuaAZgIaYKgBiANhXACIXEUCyA9gCYL0AeACqgAvKABGXLvQQUkAPlABvAqHWgAbhXoBXBAC5QQgNwEAvgQJFSqStTqM42Vu259BajSIQAPUkg82KAASgiYXKg8AtjEGEhwADSOTK6cvPxK4mERUTFxREkpLGzpHgoESqr4GqBkTtgA-EamFlb4IKAAwrqxXAC2oOj9AA6y-cjsxOhcSATIuoM9ff0AchQTwdW1tADyu2KgAOSYvcQDALRk0keJXuoAQuAhhydnlxIUqEdt+ATEAE8RjRlud+gwmC5Su5+IcIc40jDBNsNABtUEDdabAB0TxCAF0jPDERl6HcamiMWsNghsNi9rtCcUSR4LAozH8OmAIkhYqAeZhUAhSPCoewjFTRSzYeJqp1avVIUY5WBarV0e9qTi8UzlFodPojHF9KBzOT5Wr1BqVljafT9rr9XpDHUdNgaJYuWrPZ1PQROlBYP0KADQELiLpUEhQFwJAArcLEUD0dAAaxoxAAFug8PgeXzECgMJgpaUiQ1pfRDij1IrnMr7mq3isrjdlU7DaBjR7yZb1M2wRdPt929pnUbUCazY3agPLtdY18jqODS7u6be325-0h18F8uVB215OPY3PeYOfmk6cVqXxd1NXeyjL4Mg0Fgn5fZtgZAhsfQuDgAAKG8wSfa0wVtOkdQASlAToBAuC5QGwTMuF0egeGTQDDzHTt13MIA). Any ideas?